# How to write an aggregate query for nested documents?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
user Schema

_id: ObjectId
applications: [
    {
        jobId: ObjectId
        status: String (can be accepted / rejected / active)
    },
]
```

This is my schema for each user on my web app. I want the mongo query I can use for the following:

For an array of jobIDs, I need to find out the aggregate sums of all the users who have applied to the job grouped by the status. So for example,

```
For [10,20,34,53] Job IDs, I need to get the following output:

[
    { jobId: 10, 
      accepted: 20 (20 users have been accepted)
      rejected: 17 (17 users have been rejected)
      active: 12 (12 users have active applications)
    },
    { jobId: 20, 
      accepted: 20 (20 users have been accepted)
      rejected: 17 (17 users have been rejected)
      active: 12 (12 users have active applications)
    },
    .
    .
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following query, I have used [$unwind](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjHo-TJ1e_rAhVHzDgGHUHnB7kQFjAAegQICxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.mongodb.com%2Fmanual%2Freference%2Foperator%2Faggregation%2Funwind&usg=AOvVaw0wP4P3e7aYOC1JPY9ffHBM) and then [$group](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiY4P3a1e_rAhV8wTgGHRVTBa0QFjAAegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.mongodb.com%2Fmanual%2Freference%2Foperator%2Faggregation%2Fgroup&usg=AOvVaw0MVgG1pc0JMq3GdNlnB-MB) to group by `jobId`

```
db.user.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$applications" },
    { "$match": { "applications.jobId": { "$in": [10, 20, 34, 53]  } }},
    { "$group": { 
         "_id":"$applications.jobId",
         "jobId": { "$first": "$applications.jobId"},
         "accepted": { "$sum": {"$cond": [{"$eq": ["$applications.status","accepted"] }, 1, 0 ]} },
         "rejected": {"$sum": {"$cond": [{"$eq": ["$applications.status","rejected"] }, 1, 0 ]} },
         "active": {"$sum": {"$cond": [{"$eq": ["$applications.status", "active"] }, 1, 0 ]} }
    } }
])
```

I have tested the above query here, [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TtYioHmfpHn)